# Do App Login access tokens expire?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

The documentation clearly says that access tokens expire in the Client Credentials flow. However, it is not clear if access tokens expire in the App Login flow.

From the docs --

> App Login allows you to take various administrative
>   actions for your app, such as retrieving Insights data...
>   Graph API calls that require an app access token are
>   clearly denoted in the API reference

Here's an example of App Login --

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
  client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
  grant_type=client_credentials
```

... and the response:

```
access_token=166942940015970|tcOoRAAQrWcDm_84h3O7NN7Z9DM
```

Note that there's no `expires` parameter in the response.

My question is: do the access tokens expire in the App Login flow, and if so do I need to refresh the access token regularly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no, unless you change the app secret